# Авторизация при подключении к wi-fi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, авторизация, tp-link, lubuntu

Здраствуйте, такой вот вопрос. Есть сервер lubuntu(можно поставить и другую) c 2мя сетевыми картами. На первую приходит интернет, вторая перекидывает его на роутер tp-link. Как сделать на этом настроить этот сервер, чтобы при подключении к wi-fi выводилась сперва какая-то страница(хоть hello worl). 
В интернете читал, половина не рабочая. А другая смотрите, я вот сделал. А как не покажу.

Может кто объяснит как это реализовать или даст пару годных статей.

Comment: авторизация для доступа в инернет?

Comment: Именно так. При подкл. чтобы перенаправляла на страницу авторизации.

Comment: вы копали в сторону radius-server или WNAM ?